# Call a PHP Link with Onclick

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, curl, web

This isn't a duplicate question by any means and I have tried a lot finding solutions.So, please read it before down voting.

[image]

**Background:**

This application is like a note-taking web app where you can post/delete your notes.

**Each item in the list has an id which is needed when making a delete call.**

In my application, I have to delete individual items from a list which is generated by looping over a JSON response (by a REST API) using PHP.The JSON response can be obtained after successful login.

**Question:**

To implement **delete functionality** I have to send id of each of the items as a parameter to the rest api delete call.

So, for this I have to **generate dynamic links** of the form :

```
http://localhost/myfolder/api/notes/:id
```

which should be passed to the delete.php function (Which I have implemented in CURL).

I searched for possible ways :

1. Using a PHP function: It seems to be complex, however if there is some way to invoke a PHP function (the delete code using CURL) on click of a link (Which I found not possible as per some answers ?) this could be a great solution.
2. Using Javascript: I have to call a function upon click of link that sets a variable $_SESSION["id"] to the current item["id"] and then goes to delete.php where I use the $_SESSION variable to first set up the link and then use the CURL code.

I tried basic implementation using the second approach but I have hit a roadblock in this issue. It would be great if you could tell with a bit of code which approach should be followed or any other way to do this ?

This functionality is present in twitter/facebook and almost every such service, how do they implement this, **the basic approach should be the same, right: Generate dynamic links and pass them to a php script on click** ?

Basic Javasript approach :

```
   <script>
    <script>
    var el = document.getElementById('del1');
    el.onclick = del1;


    function del() {
      // I have to set $_SESSION here
      return false;
    }
    </script>

   echo "<a href=\"delete.php\" title=\"Delete\" id=\"del1\">"; 
   //Here, I have to pass the item["id"] to the javascript function.
```

I had tried some other ways but I have modified the code a lot so, I can't post them. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You could embed GET variables in the links when they are first generated. So your dynamic link would look something like 'delete.php?id=3&delete=yes

Comment: You can rewrite URL's with apache: https://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/

Comment: Could you share your basic implementation, please?

Comment: @fast I am updating the question.please check.

Comment: very simple to do using a click handler in javascript that makes an ajax request

Comment: @JoeSwindell Could you please explain a bit further, this method looks very easy.

Comment: @Florentino I would append the ID on to your delete link using php. echo '<a href="delete.php'.$_GET['id'].'>Delete this item</a>';

Comment: @JoeSwindell delete.php is  the file I am calling to delete the item by making a request to localhost/items/:id using CURL.So, will your approach work ?

Answer (score 2):

Regarding #2, you can't access the user's session from Javascript, so that will not work.

My preferred way (if using jquery) is to put the id in a data attribute of the delete button (or the block as a whole).  Then in the delete onclick function do something like

```
<div class="block" data-itemid="<?=$item['id']?>">
    ...
    <div class="delete_button">Delete</div>
</div>
```

...

```
$('.delete_button').on('click',function(event) {
    block = $(event).target.parent('.block');
    itemid = block.data('itemid');
    $.post('delete.php',[itemid: itemid]...);
});
```

Comment: should add one more part...success handler to delete the html for that `row`

Comment: Of course.  That would go in the '...' part of the post call :)

Comment: @JayK I get the idea. It would be really very helpful if you could explain a bit more over what is happening in code ? Thanks a lot.

Comment: When the event is fired, find the target of the event (which will be the delete button), then get the data-itemid attribute, which will be the id of the item... then send that to your php script with an ajax request.  That is very jquery specific (which I would recommend using if you aren't).  See https://api.jquery.com/ for documentation.